# good free PDF library for Delphi

Tags: delphi, pdf-generation

is there a good and free PDF generator library for delphi ?

I need one with multipage + graphics support.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487290/delphi-pdf-generation?

Comment: I imagine it's not a real duplicate since this one asks only for free libraries...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Free power pdf

[www.est.hi-ho.ne.jp/takeshi_kanno/powerpdf](http://www.est.hi-ho.ne.jp/takeshi_kanno/powerpdf/)

Comment: The site is not available any more.

Answer (score 6):

**SynPDF.pas**

PDF file generation

this unit is a part of the freeware Synopse framework,

licensed under a MPL/GPL/LGPL tri-license; version 1.16

http://synopse.info

Comment: To be more precise, used by the mORMot framework, but separated from it. You can use it stand-alone. Free and able to create a PDF from a TCanvas / TMetaFile (unique feature for Open Source PDF units).

Comment: This lib only for generating PDF. Not for open and works with PDF :(

Answer (score 4):

I'm using [PDFtoolkit VCL](http://www.gnostice.com/PDFtoolkit_VCL.asp), it is excellent. Works in Delphi 7 to Delphi 2010.

Comment: This one is not free

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [wPDF](http://www.wpcubed.com//products/wpdf/index.htm) for about three years. It is simple to use, comes with examples, and can be extended pretty easily. It works with old and new versions Delphi up to 2010. It's not free but it does have a trial.

Comment: This one is not free

Answer (score 1):

Can be easy ported to Delphi.

The library "Free JPDF Pascal" is written entirely in "Free Pascal" pure. It was created from the conversion of the FPDF library code written in PHP (http://www.fpdf.org).

You do not need the LCL. It can be used to generate PDF reports for Desktop Applications, Web CGI and / or Mobile.

Download: http://github.com/jepafi/Free-JPDF-Pascal

Answer (score 0):

There is also [Quick PDF Library](http://www.quickpdflibrary.com/), which I have not used myself but only had a quick look at the trial. They have a Lite version (ActiveX only) which is free, and which may meet your needs.

Comment: Last version works only in Delphi 10.3. Delphi 11 is not supporting :(