# Print from Android App (Delphi FireMonkey)

Tags: android, delphi, printing, firemonkey, twebbrowser

I'm creating a small Android App (Delphi XE7 + FireMonkey) and from it, I need to print some information.
Since no reporting component (that I know of) works on FireMonkey for Android, I've been persuing some options, and one of them was to create a html file with some tags in the places I need to fill in the information from the app.
When the user gives the order to print, I read the file to a TStringList, replace all the tags with the required info, save it to a temp file and open it in a TWebBrowser.
I then use a standard action ShareSheet to open the sharing options, and send it to a Google Cloud Printer.

Unfortunatelly, I'm not being able to control the outcome quite like I would want to.
I prepared the html in Windows, and tried it in Google Chrome, and it fits in a A4 (210x297) sheet perfectly, but in TWebBrowser, I can't even get the aspect ratio right. It's like the measurements aren't the same, and even if I use Align = Client, the TWebBrowser won't fill the screen of the 7" tablet, which is more or less the A4 aspect ratio.

Furthermore, I'm then use TWebBrowser.CaptureBitMap to assign it to ShareSheet, but it won't pass the whole canvas, only the part that is visible at that particular moment.

Any ideas on how to fix this, or any other method to do the printing?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be best if you go and prepare PDF file instead of HTML. The main problem of HTML is that it laregly depends on how does the web browser renders it (auto aligning based on browser width, etc).

To find more information on which components to use I recomend you check the next thread
[Any good PDF export filter that works with Fast Report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844831/any-good-pdf-export-filter-that-works-with-fast-report)