# frxPDFexport and frxReport component in Fast Reports 4 does not export high quality images

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I using FR4 VCL components in a software written in Delphi 7. In some reports i using images with high quality. But when i'm trying to export report to a PDF file using frxPDFExport component, the quality of images in exported PDF are poor.

```
frxPDFExport.Filename := 'D:\temp\exported_files\example.pdf';
frxReport1.Export(frxPDFExport);
```

I changed the properties of my frxPDFExport component, but it doesn't helped me. The changes that i applied to frxPDFExport:

```
    Compressed: False;
    PrintOptimized: False;
    OpenAFterExport : true;
    UseFileCache: true;
    HTML Tags: true;
```

If you can, please provide the solution of my problem. 
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried PrintOptimized: True? Usually that improves the images.

Comment: You may try to use a more advanced PDF generation units, like our [Open Source SynPDF unit - there is some code available on our forums to handle it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4274706/458259). You can use bitmaps with JPEG compression (low quality) or with DEFLATE compression (high quality). And vectorial images (EMF/WMF) will be converted as vectorial PDF commands - so with higher quality possible.